# Change the commands in manifest.json by user input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm building a chrome extension and I have commands set in my manifest.json file as follows:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Project X",
"description": "Quick lanch Project X",
"version": "0.0.1",
"icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": ["activeTab"],
"background":
{
    "scripts": ["popup.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"commands": {
    "execute-browser-action": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
          "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
        },
        "description": "Toggle feature foo"
        
    }
}
```

}

My question is: Is it possible to change the default and mac keys (Ctrl+Shift+Y) to something else, during runtime? Specifically decided by the user?

Comment: I think, you can change the shortcut key from this url `chrome://extensions/shortcuts`.

Comment: In Chrome there's no such API method, only the UI page mentioned above.

Comment: @Noobdev Thanks a lot, if you wanna answer normally I can select you as the accepted answer